# Find periods before @ symbol

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the periods in an email address before the @ symbol.  For example in email address  Mike.Beers.jr@hotmail.com  I want to match the . between Mike and Beers and the . between Beers and Jr.   I do not want to match between hotmail and com.

Here is what I have

```
(\.*?)(?=@).
```

It seems to only match the @ symbol but not the periods.

Comment: Try `\.(?=[^@]*@)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I'd add `\s` to the negated class as in [**`\.(?=[^\s@]*@)`**](https://regex101.com/r/5uJoV9/1/) but it surely depends on what OP wants.

Comment: @Jan, well, actually, `\.(?=.*@)` might be best since there can be `@` in the username part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Wiktor Stribizew in the comments: (\.)(?=.*@) is likely the answer you're looking for if you're looking to capture the periods themselves.

That said, I'd check out this awesome website on regex: https://regexr.com

It let's you enter any string and test all sorts of regular expressions on it. I've used it to scan whole documents before.

Breaking down that regex:
You have a capturing group (\.) that looks for and captures all periods. You then modify the expression with a positive lookahead (?=.*@). The positive lookahead contains the "@" symbol and a wildcard which allows basically any string to be between the period itself and the wildcard.